# É uma boa prática utilizar chaves compostas como chave primária?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Não possuo muito conhecimento em estruturação de banco de dados. Tenho tentado me aprimorar mais e estou buscando melhores práticas em como criar e estruturar tabelas.

Atualmente costumo criar tabelas de ligação e combinar os ID's de cada tabela transformando eles em uma chave primária (ou chave composta).

Isso é uma boa prática ou se eu deveria sempre criar uma chave primária para cada tabela?

Comment: relacionado: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html, não responde à sua pergunta, mas pode lhe ajudar à entender alguns fatores.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A chave primária tem duas funções principais:

- Identificar de forma inequívoca um registo da tabela
- Ser usada na definição de relacionamentos entre tabelas.

Embora uma chave primária simples ou uma composta sirvam para esse efeito, a chave primária simples tem as seguintes vantagens.

1 - É facilmente criada automaticamente pelo motor do banco, não sendo necessário verificar se ela existe antes de fazer o INSERT.
2 - A definição de relacionamentos é simplificado porque só é usado uma coluna.
3 - A unicidade pode ser facilmente obtida recorrendo a um índice único(UNIQUE INDEX) nos campos compostos.

Note que "Identificar inequivocamente" é diferente de "garantir unicidade". A primeira é função da chave primária enquanto a segunda é função de um índice declarado como *UNIQUE INDEX*.

Se é uma boa prática não sei, mas as razões acima para mim são suficientes para eu usar chaves primárias simples(automáticas).

Answer (score 7):

Esqueça esse negócio de "boas práticas". Aprenda tudo o que é necessário (este site é ótimo para esclarecer suas dúvidas), analise o problema específico e aplique a melhor técnica para o caso. Boa prática é seguir receita de bolo cegamente, é procurar uma solução única para todos os casos e isso não funciona bem.

As chaves compostas existem porque elas são úteis. Se existe uma chave natural que pode ser adequada e se a chave natural é formada por mais de uma coluna, pode usar sem problema. Só tenha certeza que essa chave é realmente é adequada.

É muito comum o pessoal achar que uma chave natural é adequada e na verdade não ser. Ela pode ser ótima em determinado momento e depois mostrar-se problemática. Por isso é muito comum se optar por uma chave substituta, como o tal do `ID` ou algo parecido.

Eu particularmente sempre analiso por padrão se é possível usar uma chave natural. Quase sempre a decisão é que não pode.

Em alguns casos pode-se pensar em usar uma chave substituta composta, ainda que alguns dirão que na verdade ela acaba sendo natural. Uma chave que seja um `ID` (que funciona como chave estrangeira também) mais um número sequencial do item, é uma chave que pode ser considerada substituta e ser composta. Isso é comum em cadastros de pedidos, por exemplo.

As tabelas de ligação costumam ser assim, quase sempre usam chaves estrangeiras relacionadas à duas ou mais tabelas e juntas formam uma chave primária composta. Uso bem adequado na maioria das situações. Acho bem raro precisar uma chave substituta para isso, mas pode ocorrer necessidade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu agradeço pelo sua resposta bigown. Mas descordo quando você diz. "Esqueça esse negócio de 'boas práticas'. Da mesma forma que você diz "As chaves compostas existem porque elas são úteis". As boas práticas também existem porque elas são muito úteis. Acho que apenas cabe a nós desenvolvedores saber até onde segui-las de acordo com as nossas necessidades. Concordo com você de que não devemos seguir cegamente as boas práticas. Mas acredito que seguir boas práticas e padrões e essencial para desenvolver bem um projeto.

Comment: @Alan você pode discordar, mas boas práticas não são úteis, fazer o certo é útil. Seguir o que não se entende é bem prejudicial para qualquer projeto. E boa prática é dizer "faça isso" sem explicar porque.  minha extensiva experiência mostra que elas causam mais problemas do que ajudam. Vou dizer novamente. Entender qual o problema, qual a solução, porque aquilo acontece e aplicar algo de acordo com o caso é útil. Regrinha do tipo "faça isso, não faça aquilo" só cria problemas. Cada problema é único. Se a pergunta falasse de um caso concreto específico, aí para dar uma uma resposta específica.

Comment: Bom. Para mim tem sido muito útil. Eu concordo com você em muitas coisas que você disse. Mas acho que ficaremos cada um de um lado nesta! kkkk! Bom de qualquer forma. Obrigado por compartilhar um pouco da sua experiência comigo!

Comment: @Alan Eu programo há muitos anos, sempre tentando fazer melhor, e faz um tempo que boas práticas em software não me são mais tão úteis. Mas eu tô sempre aprendendo coisas novas pra mim: jogar tênis, tocar guitarra, construir móveis, escalar montanhas... Cada vez que tento aprender algo fora do software sempre fica evidente pra mim que boas práticas existem em todos os campos, e o que seria de nós iniciantes sem os instrutores que nos mostram bons caminhos nos permitindo fazer bem feito já no começo, mesmo antes de entendermos ainda totalmente o que estamos fazendo? Viva as boas práticas! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Boas práticas existem para prevenir problemas futuros.

São recomendadas por quem passa por experiências das quais outros poderiam algum dia experimentar. Normalmente algo inevitável.

Quando torna-se algo comum e inevitável de ocorrer, então é difundido como uma precaução.

Para ser mais claro, um exemplo prático de uso de chave primária, mesmo com chave composta, é a performance no momento de uma replicação de dados (replication). Quando não há um índice identificador explícito, a replicação leva mais tempo para encontrar uma unicidade.

Por fim, não é obrigatório uma tabela possuir chave primária, porém é recomendado que tenha. Pela razão acima descrita no exemplo do estudo de caso com replicação de dados e outros casos diversos, obviamente todos relacionados com performance e unicidade que identifique "aquele" row como único.