# É necessário criar uma chave primária com auto increment?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-primária, índices

Quando crio uma tabela que já possui um campo com um índice `unique`, que será referenciado por outras tabelas, posso deixá-lo como chave primária? Ou é uma boa prática criar outro campo, com `auto increment`, para este propósito?

Por exemplo: Em uma tabela funcionários, com o campo nome e matrícula, onde este será do tipo `varchar`, terá valores únicos, e será referenciado por outras tabelas, das seguintes alternativas, qual é a mais correta? E por que?

1. Apenas deixar o campo matrícula como a chave primária.
2. Deixar o campo matrícula com um índice `unique` e criar um campo id com `auto increment` para ser a chave primária.
3. Deixar o campo matrícula como a chave primária e criar um campo id com índice `auto increment`, para ser auxiliar.

Comment: [É recomendado usar chave primária natural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28507/91) e [É uma boa prática utilizar chaves compostas como chave primária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146066/91)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você quer saber se é melhor usar uma [chave natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) ou [substituta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (*surrogate*).

> Apenas deixar o campo matrícula como a chave primária.

Isso é uma chave natural. Você controla esse número? Ele nunca será mudado? Não há a menor chance do mesmo objeto no banco de dados um dia precisar ter outra identificação única? Ela é curta o suficiente? Ela não dá margem para erros? Ela sempre será única? Ela realmente identifica o que é o objeto?

A maioria dos dados existentes no mundo não atendem todos esses critérios, por isso opta-se por uma chave substituta. Se atender tudo isso, pode usar sem problemas. Mas cuidado, muita gente acha que atende e um dia descobre que não atende, era algo circunstancial.

> Deixar o campo matrícula com um índice `unique` e criar um campo id com auto increment para ser a chave primária.

Isso é uma chave substituta. É interessante em muitos casos para manter um controle interno no sistema independente do número que o usuário lida. Não posso afirmar que é o melhor no seu caso. Se pode fazer bem o item anterior então não tem porque fazer isto, está só desperdiçando espaço e performance.

> Deixar o campo matrícula como a chave primária e criar um campo `id` com índice `auto increment`, para ser auxiliar.

Não me parece vantagem alguma nisso.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa sempre há uma chave primária em toda tabela. Até mesmo quando o banco de dados não exige que crie uma (ele cria sem você saber). Também ao contrário da crença popular, a chave primária sempre é um índice. Os dados sempre são classificados no banco de dados pela chave primária. Os índices secundários costumam se referir ao índice primário.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: Muito obrigado, minha duvida foi totalmente esclarecida.

Answer (score 2):

1) Teoricamente não teria problema em fazê-lo, depende de como seu app irá lidar com esta PK. Pois tera fragmentos adicionais de códigos para validar se a PK é única, válida, etc. Mas não seria bem visto pela maioria dos Dev's.

2) Indices são para tunnar a base em relação à pesquisas e não para gerenciar Primary Keys.

3) Fazendo assim você estaria agregando uma complexidade desnecessária, tipo chave composta e deveria tratar isso dentro do app. Não faça isso!

Eu aconselho o uso do **Surrogate Key**, que é a coluna (ID) utilizada para identificar cada linha na tabela de **forma única**. Geralmente usa-se INT como tipo de dados para ID, porém se houver uma integração externa de dados, é bom usar GUID. E o campo matrícula será apenas uma propriedade do registro e, caso necessário, eu criaria um índice para ele.

Há casos em que se pode usar **Sequences**, como no Oracle por exemplo para PK's. Vale a pena ler sobre sequences também.

[Surrogate key](https://rafaelpiton.com.br/data-warehouse-surrogate-key/)

Comment: O uso de uma Surrogate Key se enquadraria na segunda alternativa da questão? E neste caso, seria mais adequado referenciar o ID em outras tabelas, em vez do campo matrícula?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso. Seria a forma que eu faria.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que não seria viável para a minha aplicação, pois as tabelas que irão apontar para tabela funcionarios serão importadas, assim eu tenho que referenciar o campo matricula mesmo, que já vêm pré defenido. Mas muito obrigado pelas susgetões, ajudou muito e esclareceu bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo o campo chave primaria ser sempre um número, até ao porque ordenar um varchar você terá um resultado diferente.
Com os valores "1,2,3,4,11,21".

```
em Inteiro: 1,2,3,4,11,21

em varchar: 1,11,2,21,3,4
```

Além de as consultas se tornarem mais rápidas por que o índice numérico é melhor otimizado.

E como o amigo disse:

> Você controla esse número? Ele nunca será mudado? Não há a menor
>   chance do mesmo objeto no banco de dados um dia precisar ter outra
>   identificação única? Ela é curta o suficiente? Ela não dá margem para
>   erros? Ela sempre será única? Ela realmente identifica o que é este
>   objeto?

Se essas perguntas forem respondidas então use sua chave primaria.